# Is there a better way to do with_options in Rails 3 routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-routing

Here are my Rails 2 routes:

```
map.with_options :controller => 'foo', :conditions => { :method => :post } do |foo|
  foo.one 'one', :action => 'one'
  foo.two 'two', :action => 'two'

  foo.with_options :special_flag => 'true', :path_prefix => 'special_prefix',
    :conditions => { :method => :get } do |bar|
    bar.three '',        :action => 'for_blank'
    bar.four  'another', :action => 'for_another'
  end
end
```

How do I convert this sort of thing to Rails 3? Just keep using with_options in the same way? It becomes wordier in some cases because instead of doing

```
match '' => 'foo#for_blank'
```

I'm doing

```
match '', :action => 'for_blank'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, `with_options` still works in Rails 3. Try this out:

```
map.with_options :controller => 'foo', :via => :post do
  match 'one', :action => 'one' #automatically generates one_* helpers
  match 'two', :action => 'two' #automatically generates two_* helpers

  foo.with_options :special_flag => 'true', :path => 'special_prefix', :via => :get do
    match '',        :action => 'for_blank'
    match  'another', :action => 'for_another', :as => "four" # as will change the helper methods names
  end
end
```

The `:via` option replaces your ugly `conditions` hash with a much nicer syntax.

Comment: sweet. also i can leave out via and do `post 'one'` and `post 'two'`, yes?

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
#JSON API
defaults :format => 'json' do
    get "log_out" => "sessions#destroy", :as => "log_out" 
    get "log_in"  => "sessions#new",     :as => "log_in" 
    get "sign_up" => "users#new",        :as => "sign_up" 

    resources :users, :sessions
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to stick to the methods the routes provide. They are very powerful in Rails 3 and should provide everything you need. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html for more details

Comment: I read that carefully, didn't find much other than `scope` which doesn't help me, but just now I dug a little deeper in the api and found the likes of  `controller "food" do`… That will do the trick! http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Scoping.html#method-i-controller

Comment: hmmm indeed, `controller` is missing... oh well... too many methods in a controller isn't considered to be okay, so that might be the reason. good to know you found a solution anyway.